# Проблемы с 'count'

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь реализовать расписание занятий с возможностью записи.
Разобрался как сделать так, что-бы кнопка работала именно в том блоке в котором стоит, но возник со следующей проблемой.
По моей логике при нажатии на "Записаться" должно происходить для первой карточки 7+1=8, но получается что в какую бы из трех карточке я бы не делал это, все начинается 6+1=7 (как я понял все подставляется из последней карточки где указано изначально 6)

```
async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('data.json');
        if (!response) {
            throw new Error('Не удалось обработать data.json');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        const lessonsBox = document.querySelector('.lessons-box');

        data.forEach(({id, maxPeople, currentPeople}) => {
            const lessonsEl = `
                <div class="lesson-item" id="${id}">
                        <p>Максимальное количество участников</p>
                        <p class="max-people">${maxPeople}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="current-people-box">
                        <p>Текущее количество участников</p>
                        <p class="count-people">${currentPeople}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="sing-up">Записаться</button>
                    <button class="сancel-recording">Отменить запись</button>
                </div>
            `;
            lessonsBox.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lessonsEl);

            const allBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.sing-up');
    
            let count = 1;
        
            allBtn.forEach(button => {
                button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    const lessonItem = button.closest('.lesson-item');
        
                    const countPeople = lessonItem.querySelector('.count-people');
                    countPeople.innerHTML = currentPeople + count;
                    count++;
        
                })
            })
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    };
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "maxPeople": 10,
        "currentPeople": 7  
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "maxPeople": 10,
        "currentPeople": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "maxPeople": 10,
        "currentPeople": 6
    }
]
```

HTML

```
<div class="lessons-box"></div>
```

Comment: У вас переменная `count` имеет одно значение для всех элементов. Попробуйте создать объект, где ключами будут иды блоков `lessons-items`, а значениями -  количество участников

Comment: И также в константе `lessonsEl`, очевидно, `div.lesson-item` закрывается в ненужном месте